# GeoTools class VectorToRasterFactory is no more

Tags: geotools

I'm very new to GIS and GeoTools too. I'm upgrading org.geotools dependencies of a Maven project from `2.7.0` to `15.2`. I got a compilation error about `VectorToRasterFactory`, It looks like there is no `VectorToRasterFactory` in the newest libraries. I didn't found any docs about how to substitute this class or how to get the same features.

**UPDATE**
I upgrade the libs but I got an issue during runtime. Here is the code:

```
...
GridCoverage2D cov = null;
try {
    org.geotools.process.Process p = Processors.createProcess(new NameImpl("vec", "VectorToRaster"));
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put(AbstractFeatureCollectionProcessFactory.FEATURES.key, srcCollection);
    map.put("attribute", "value");
    map.put("rasterWidth", dimension.width);
    map.put("rasterHeight", dimension.height);
    map.put("bounds", bounds);
    Map<String, Object> result = p.execute(map, monitor);
    cov = (GridCoverage2D) result.get("result");
    return (PlanarImage) cov.getRenderedImage();
} finally {
    if (cov != null)
    cov.dispose(true);
}
...
```

I can't get a `Process` instance, `Processors.createProces...` always returns null.

Comment: Please edit your question to show your full error. It will help with troubleshooting.

Comment: @MaryBeth Hello. My error is a compile error due to VectorToRasterFactory is removed in earlier versions.

Comment: please show the code you are using

Answer (score 1):

It seems not to be needed any longer - the [VectorToRasterProcess](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/42c4cc0c3d850b1dea50c07108f171aace35a798/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/vector/VectorToRasterProcess.java) has moved to the **unsupported** process-features module. From looking at the [unit tests](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/42c4cc0c3d850b1dea50c07108f171aace35a798/modules/unsupported/process-feature/src/test/java/org/geotools/process/vector/VectorToRasterProcessTest.java) you can just do:

```
    Process p = Processors.createProcess(new NameImpl("vec", "VectorToRaster"));
    SimpleFeatureCollection features = createPolys();
    ReferencedEnvelope bounds = features.getBounds();

    Dimension gridDim = new Dimension(
            (int)bounds.getWidth(),
            (int)bounds.getHeight());

    String covName = "Test";
    ProgressListener monitor = null;

    GridCoverage2D cov = p.process(
            features, "value", gridDim, bounds, covName, monitor);
```

Comment: hello, I am back on this issue again. Yes this must be the way but I am having some hard times about `Processors.createProcess(...)`. I can't get anything but `null`. Any hint?

Comment: I also edit my question. The geotools version we want to upgrade to is now 15.2. Thanks.